# Time doesn't get trimmed in DateTime.ParseExact

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, ado.net, datetime-parsing

I have a textbox control as

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TxtStartDate" runat="server" CssClass="Text1"></asp:TextBox>
```

which takes a date and time but I want to send only a date to the database.

```
DateTime.ParseExact(TxtStartDate.Text.Trim(), "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
```

I am using this at cs page but it doesn't trim the time. What possibles error are there?

Answer (score 2):

> i want to send only a date to database.

Use the [`Date`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx) property on your `DateTime` object.

```
Console.Write(yourDateTimeObject.Date);
```

This will not trim the `Time` but will set the time to `12:00:00 midnight (00:00:00)`.

Answer (score 1):

> I am using this at cs page but it doesn't trim the time.

Trim is not supposed to trim the time part of your textbox. Either remove the time part from textbox or include the time part in format of DateTime.ParseExact.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(TxtStartDate.Text.Trim(), "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss", null);
DateTime onlyDate = dt.Date;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact(TxtStartDate.Text.Trim(), "yyyy-MM-dd",
                                   System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```